# How to skip splash page when scraping script runs

Tags: python-3.x, xpath, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm building webpage scraping script with Python3.5 now. The problem I'm having here is this site.

http://www.forbes.com/sites/julianmitchell/2016/09/27/this-startup-uses-drones-to-map-and-manage-massive-construction-projects/print/

Forbes.com forces user to see the splash page when any article link is clicked.

Here is the splash page URL.

http://www.forbes.com/forbes/welcome/?toURL=http://www.forbes.com/sites/julianmitchell/2016/09/27/this-startup-uses-drones-to-map-and-manage-massive-construction-projects&refURL=&referrer=

The prefix URL is embedded automatically, so I cannot remove it.
Also, I'd like to reach ...forbes.com/.../print/ so that I can scrape entire article but the site redirects to the page without "/print/".

When I tried to excerpt article with Xpath or Beautifulsoup by designating tag, it won't work because the script is stuck in this welcome splash page.

```
import lxml.html
from selenium import webdriver

target_url = 'http://www.forbes.com/sites/julianmitchell/2016/09/27/this-startup-uses-drones-to-map-and-manage-massive-construction-projects/print/'
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
driver.get(target_url)
root = lxml.html.fromstring(driver.page_source)

content = str(root.xpath('//div[@class="body_inner"]/p[position() >= 1 and position() <= last()]/text()'))


print(content)
```

What's the best way to skip welcome page? and what needs to be done so that I can reach to .../print/ page?

Comment: I don't understand what is the problem here. Can't you just open forbes, wait for sometime for it to kill the splash screen and then do whatever you want to do with it ?

Comment: @testerjoe2 I mean I'd like to automate the scraping process. I won't open the forbes page by myself. My python script will access to it and get the article. If the script hit the URL, it will be caught up by the splash page. What's the best way to let the script "wait" in my code?  I don't know where to put **time sleep(30)** for example.

Comment: Where to put the wait should be obvious, if you've written the above script yourself.

Comment: Tried time.sleep but it did not help.. What would be the another approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: I have explained the way to click on skip button as soon as it will be clickable and not verified the lxml logic of code.

This can be a approach using Explicit wait where it will click the button as soon as it will be clickable

```
import lxml.html
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

target_url = 'http://www.forbes.com/sites/julianmitchell/2016/09/27/this-startup-uses-drones-to-map-and-manage-massive-construction-projects/print/'
driver = webdriver.Chrome("pathtochromedriver\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get(target_url)
driver.maximize_window()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 5)
skipbutton = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="navigation"]/div/a')))
skipbutton.click()

root = lxml.html.fromstring(driver.page_source)

content = str(root.xpath('//div[@class="body_inner"]/p[position() >= 1 and position() <= last()]/text()'))


print(content)
```

**Update:**

With the help of this code you will get the title and paragraphs of  articles. I am using beautifulsoup...

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs4


target_url = 'http://www.forbes.com/sites/julianmitchell/2016/09/27/this-startup-uses-drones-to-map-and-manage-massive-construction-projects/print/'
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(target_url)
driver.maximize_window()
try:
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 5)
    skipbutton = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="navigation"]/div/a')))
    skipbutton.click()
    time.sleep(3)
except:
    print "Continue Button not present"

pSource= driver.page_source

soup = bs4(pSource, "html.parser")

ArticleTitle = soup.find("h1",{"itemprop":"headline"})
print "The title of Article is : " + ArticleTitle.text

Article = soup.find("div",{'itemprop':"articleBody"})
Articlebody=Article.findAll("p")

for a in Articlebody:
    print a.text
```

This is the output :

```
The title of Article is : This Startup Uses Self-Flying Drones To Map And Manage Construction sites
This is a modal window.
This is a modal window. This modal can be closed by pressing the Escape key or activating the close button.
This is a modal window. This modal can be closed by pressing the Escape key or activating the close button.
Robots replacing humans in the workforce is no longer a futuristic theory reserved for sci-fi thrillers and chats amongst alleged cyber geeks. Startups across industries are increasingly using automation and artificial intelligence to take on roles such as developing software, mining insights, curating content and managing marketing efforts.
Automation is proven to be an effective method of removing human workers from seemingly menial or repetitive tasks, empowering employees to focus on aspects of the business that require more specialized skills. This approach has shown to boost efficiency by allowing startups to scale quicker, trim budgets and consolidate their employee count.
A self-flying Boomerang Drone being used to map a construction site. (Photo courtesy of Identified Technologies)
Today’s tech-driven workforce is a direct reflection of a tech-driven culture. The digital era has swiftly transitioned from websites and mobile apps into high-tech hardware, wearable technology and the ability to experience alternative realities. One example of this integrated shift is the adoption of drones. Drones are expected to have an economic impact that exceeds $13.6 billion, while expecting to gross upward of $82 billion and create over 100,000 jobs by 2025.
Drones first surfaced as aerial combat machines acquired for military use. According to their 2017 Fiscal Year budget, the United States military will spend $4.61 billion on drones, aiming to purchase 31 unmanned aerial systems. Expanding beyond military use, drones quickly became free-range, high-definition cameras embraced by the new wave of photographers and filmmakers. Fast forward, drones are being used for everything from delivering burritos to flying into deadly storms. Now, a startup is using drones with a vision to revolutionize the construction industry.
This is a modal window.
This is a modal window. This modal can be closed by pressing the Escape key or activating the close button.
This is a modal window. This modal can be closed by pressing the Escape key or activating the close button.
Identified Technologies uses self-flying drones to map out and manage large-scale construction projects. Using physical labor, the mapping process commonly exceeds a month, from planning to execution. However, by using their advanced drone technology, the entire mapping process can be completed within minutes, allowing the process to be repeated and tracked daily without extending timelines or exhausting budgets. Other aspects of the mapping process include pre-flight planning, post-flight analysis and detailed reporting.
In addition to dramatically reducing the length of a project, drones massively reduce the likelihood of errors, producing physical maps that delivery thorough depictions of a space, capturing very intricate details. This allows Identified Technologies to complete projects with better precision than human workers. With the FAA recently modifying laws regarding drone piloting, thier technology will now become ten times more accessible, causing a rapid expansion of the drone mapping industry.
I spoke with Dick Zhang, CEO of Identified Technologies, about the vision behind his company, pioneering a new industry and how drones are continuing to disrupt the modern economy.
Every great company solves a problem or fills a void — what opportunity did you discover and how did the initial idea evolve into what Identified Technologies is today? 
Dick Zhang: I came away from a drone demonstration at the University of Pennsylvania’s GRASP Lab with an immediate sense of the potential uses for this new technology. I attached a high-resolution camera to a drone and began gathering data and experimenting with business models. It soon became apparent that the construction industry was a particularly ripe target for continuous project tracking technology.  Our customers had been stuck with antiquated methods of gathering data and making decisions that led to extremely painful surprises, reworking, costs, and delays. It wasn’t their fault, at the time, there was no alternative.  You can’t make smart decisions without accurate data and you couldn’t cost-effectively capture the necessary data without new technologies like aerial mapping drones.
How much of the appeal or value of the technology is found in the actual drone versus the other key elements associated with it?
Dick Zhang: The actual drone is just a small part of generating business value with the technology. Pre-flight planning, camera and sensor settings, post-flight analysis and quality control, in addition to reporting and analytics are all needed to make the captured data useful. Until recently, there were only fragmented ways of cobbling that workflow together. That problem led to the development of our eeDaaS model, which stands for end-to-end drone as a Service, where we handle every aspect of the workflow with our fully integrated hardware/software system.  Clients don’t want their technology vendors pointing fingers at each other when it breaks, they just want it to work. I believe the stress-free eeDaaS workflow is the biggest reason industry leaders choose us over alternatives.
What is the makeup of an operating team and how many drones does it usually take to fulfill the average construction project? 
Dick Zhang: A typical operating team consists of just one certified user. Under the new FAA Part 107 Rules, there no longer needs to be a licensed commercial pilot, they only need an easily obtainable Remote Pilot Certificate. To do a manned survey of a 100-acre site using traditional methods might have taken a month. Beyond the time, and cost, it put people in danger on hazardous construction sites, and if anything with the project isn’t on track, you won’t find out until you get your results back, when a month of labor, time and money have already been sunk into it.  In contrast, a 100-acre construction site requires just 9 minutes and a single Boomerang drone to capture the data automatically. The pre-flight preparations, take off, data capture flight, landing, post-flight processing, post-flight data analysis, reporting, and storage are all done by the system for you. That is the beauty of the eeDaaS model.
Since using drones for construction mapping is new and drone regulations continue changing — What have been the biggest challenges you’ve faced thus far and what obstacles do you expect to face going forward? 
Dick Zhang:  Our biggest challenge was balancing our aggressively advancing commercial drone technology with conservatively adopting regulatory changes.  In 2014 and 2015, it was unclear what direction and pace the FAA would adopt. I give huge credit to the FAA, with the new Part 107 rules they have updated their policies to ensure that appropriate safety controls are in place, while removing the headaches and hurdles that were needlessly holding commercial adoption back.  Now, with the 107, there is no reason for companies not to take advantage of drones and the savings, speed and safety they bring. We have wanted to bring transparency to construction industry workflows with Site IQ for years, but the market was not ready for it initially.
Your technology and approach have already proven to make the construction processes quicker, more efficient and more cost effective — What do you see your company, and this technique evolving into? 
Dick Zhang:  Our goal is to bring complete transparency to the traditionally opaque construction workflow process.  We use big data to bring big insights to big jobs. Even if you are the world’s best project manager, it’s still going to be impossible to finish on time and on budget if you can’t see your progress. We have found drones to be a total game changer for construction site mapping and analysis.  For the first time in history, managers are getting the accurate data they need to make fast informed decisions, that’s why our slogan is “Know when others guess”.  Beyond saving time and money, builders can now see details, progress, and trends that were previously impossible to detect.
```

Only problem I am seeing in this code is code is that there are three extra lines in the output i.e,

```
This is a modal window.
    This is a modal window. This modal can be closed by pressing the Escape key or activating the close button.
    This is a modal window. This modal can be closed by pressing the Escape key or activating the close button.
```

These are coming because of their tag is also 'p'.....This is interim solution to your problem, will try to rectify this problem and update here

Comment: Thanks. I could make one step further. It helps me to move on to the article page from the splash page.

Now, my question is after skipbutton.click() happened, how can I grab the article page and put it in the object?  I need to pass it to *lxml.html.formstring*, but my code (driver.page_source) is not just right.  

I experiment print(skipbutton.click()), but it returns "None".

Comment: @K.K. I have provided you interim solution for now.please check